# Code generated by Android Studio doesn't shows variable named correctly

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-sdk-tools

After installed a new development environment the code is generated by Android Studio as it doesn't knows about the source code:

[image]

[image]

See those p0, p1 named variables.

The sources are installed:

[image]

But when I enter some Sdk classes it show a button to Download the sources, but when I press that button, nothing happens.

[image]

Android Studio 3.2.1
Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October 8, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.15.0-38-generic

Answer (score 1):

Google haven't released Android P source code, so the opened file is a decompiled `AppCompatActivity.class`

If you change SDK version to **27**, and download source using SDK manager, the issue will disappear. the opened file is `AppCompatActivity.java`